# Default Ports for AddModelFromFile() with SDF

Tags: drake

What are the default input and output ports of a model that is loaded via

`model = parser.AddModelFromFile("myfile.sdf")`

?

In particular, I am wondering what the order of variables is. I'm quite confused since I am loading a robot with 10 Joints, thus I would expect

`plant.get_state_output_port(model).size()`

to be 20. I.e. 10 Joint positions, and 10 Joint velocities. However, when loading the robot the above yields 16, which to me seems rather strange. This also raises the question of how the variables are ordered, i.e. first all positions or by joint?

The sdf file I was loading is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.7">
    <model name="two_planar_cc_segments">
        <link name="robot_base">
            <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <inertial>
                <mass>0.01</mass>
                <inertia>
                  <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                  <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                  <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                  <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                  <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                  <izz>0.001</izz>
                </inertia>
            </inertial>
            <collision name="robot_base_col">
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder>
                      <length> 0.0001 </length>
                      <radius> 0.01 </radius>
                    </cylinder>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
            <visual name="robot_base_vis">
                <material>
                    <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0</diffuse>
                </material>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder>
                      <length> 0.0001 </length>
                      <radius> 0.01 </radius>
                    </cylinder>
                </geometry>
            </visual>
        </link>
        <!-- This is the first CC Segment -->
            <link name="s1l0">
                <pose relative_to="robot_base"> 0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0 </pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s1l0_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s1l0_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s1q0" type="revolute">
                <pose relative_to="robot_base"> 0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <parent> robot_base </parent>
                <child> s1l0 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz> 0 0 1 </xyz>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s1l1">
                <pose relative_to="s1l0"> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s1l1_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s1l1_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s1q1" type="revolute">
                <pose relative_to="s1q0">0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s1l0 </parent>
                <child> s1l1 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s1l2">
                <pose relative_to="s1l1"> 0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s1l2_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s1l2_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                          <length> 0.0001 </length>
                          <radius> 0.01 </radius>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s1q2" type="prismatic">
                <pose relative_to="s1q1">0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s1l1 </parent>
                <child> s1l2 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
                    <dynamics>
                        <friction>1</friction>
                        <damping>1</damping>
                    </dynamics>
                    <limit>
                        <lower>0.0</lower>
                        <upper>0.1</upper>
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s1l3">
                <pose relative_to="s1l2"> 0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s1l3_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s1l3_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                          <length> 0.0001 </length>
                          <radius> 0.01 </radius>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s1q3" type="prismatic">
                <pose relative_to="s1q2">0 0 0 -1.570796327 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s1l2 </parent>
                <child> s1l3 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
                    <dynamics>
                        <friction>1</friction>
                        <damping>1</damping>
                    </dynamics>
                    <limit>
                        <lower>0.0</lower>
                        <upper>0.1</upper>
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s1l4">
                <pose relative_to="s1l3"> 0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s1l4_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s1l4_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s1q4" type="revolute">
                <pose relative_to="s1q3">0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s1l3 </parent>
                <child> s1l4 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <frame name="s1-ee-link">
              <pose relative_to="s1q4">0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            </frame>
        <!-- Till Here -->

        <!-- This is the first CC Segment -->
            <link name="s2l0">
                <pose relative_to="s1l4"> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s2l0_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s2l0_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s2q0" type="revolute">
                <pose relative_to="s1l4"> 0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0</pose>
                <parent> s1l4 </parent>
                <child> s2l0 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz> 0 0 1 </xyz>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s2l1">
                <pose relative_to="s2l0"> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s2l1_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s2l1_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s2q1" type="revolute">
                <pose relative_to="s2q0">0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s2l0 </parent>
                <child> s2l1 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s2l2">
                <pose relative_to="s2l1"> 0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s2l2_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s2l2_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                          <length> 0.0001 </length>
                          <radius> 0.01 </radius>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s2q2" type="prismatic">
                <pose relative_to="s2q1">0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s2l1 </parent>
                <child> s2l2 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
                    <dynamics>
                        <friction>1</friction>
                        <damping>1</damping>
                    </dynamics>
                    <limit>
                        <lower>0.0</lower>
                        <upper>0.1</upper>
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s2l3">
                <pose relative_to="s2l2"> 0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s2l3_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s2l3_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                          <length> 0.0001 </length>
                          <radius> 0.01 </radius>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s2q3" type="prismatic">
                <pose relative_to="s2q2">0 0 0 -1.570796327 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s2l2 </parent>
                <child> s2l3 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
                    <dynamics>
                        <friction>1</friction>
                        <damping>1</damping>
                    </dynamics>
                    <limit>
                        <lower>0.0</lower>
                        <upper>0.1</upper>
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <link name="s2l4">
                <pose relative_to="s2l3"> 0 0 0 1.570796327 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>0.01</mass>
                    <inertia>
                      <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                      <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                      <izz>0.001</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <collision name="s2l4_col">
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="s2l4_vis">
                    <material>
                        <diffuse>0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0</diffuse>
                    </material>
                    <geometry>
                        <empty></empty>
                    </geometry>
                </visual>
            </link>
            <joint name="s2q4" type="revolute">
                <pose relative_to="s2q3">0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <parent> s2l3 </parent>
                <child> s2l4 </child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
                </axis>
            </joint>
            <frame name="s2-ee-link">
              <pose relative_to="s2q4">0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            </frame>
        <!-- Till Here -->
    </model>
</sdf>
```

Comment: I suspect the reason that only 16 dofs show up instead of 20 is that some joints are welded. It'd be helpful if you could provide the actual sdf file. The variables are ordered such that the positions, q, come first, followed by the velocities, v.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I don't think any of the Joints are welded since I can control their positions using the joint sliders... But maybe I'm overlooking something. I added the sdf file to my original post.

Comment: As shown in the deepnote snippet provided by Eric below, you do end up with 10 q's and v's each when you weld the base. When the base is floating, you get 7 more q's (3 for x,y,z, and 4 for the quaternion), and 6 more v's (3 for linear velocity and 3 for angular velocity). I'm not sure how you end up with 16 *total* dofs. If you need further assistance, posting the source code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Xuchen mentioned, it's because your model is by default floating.

If you wish to fixture the model, then you should get the desired coordinates you want; alternatively, you may need to mask the DoFs you want.

Example: [quick deepnote ipynb](https://deepnote.com/workspace/eric-cousineau-e535cf6a-00f3-480c-9159-0921a172db72/project/Quick-Drake-Notebooks-76437aa2-814f-4e4d-844c-5a6c087049e2/%2Fso72967765.ipynb)